# SQL(MS Access) syntax

Tags: sql, ms-access

Trying to find all these that are not in warehouse number 3 and unit price less than 100. Whats wrong with my code?

```
select part_number,
           part_description,
           Units_on_Hand,
           Unit_price,
           Warehouse_number
from part
where unit_price >= 100
and not in warehouse_number = 3;
```

Comment: Hi Clay - you might want to read [Ask] and [MCVE] - specifically for this question you could probably have got a better response by including whatever error you're seeing, and referring to that error in the question title (we can tell it's sql/access from the tags, even on the questions page).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT part_number, part_description, Units_on_Hand, Unit_price, Warehouse_number 
FROM part 
Where unit_price >= 100 AND warehouse_number NOT IN (3);
```

Comment: still receiving error message with that to and i dont get why. I appreciate the effort though thank you

Comment: Thank you sorry i had a simple data type mismatch

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `not in`.  You can do:

```
where unit_price >= 100 and
      not (warehouse_number = 3);
```

Or:

```
where unit_price >= 100 and
      warehouse_number not in (3);
```

Or:

```
where unit_price >= 100 and
      warehouse_number <> 3;
```

These are all equivalent.  The last would be the more "typical" way to write this for 1 warehouse.  The second would be the more typical way if there was more than one warehouse.

Comment: Thank you i tried those and its still giving me an error message.

Comment: select part_number,
           part_description,
           Units_on_Hand,
           Unit_price,
           Warehouse_number
from part
where unit_price >= 100 and
      warehouse_number not in (3);

Comment: data type mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: What is the data type of warehouse_number?

Comment: @Clay . . . That would suggest that either `unit_price` or `warehouse_number` are not the numbers they appear to be.

Comment: warehouse_number is a number datatype

Comment: Wow i see now it was a short text thats the issue